# Unitary number for “&” bitwise operator in c++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have a question, I would appreciate it if you helped me to understand it. Imagin I define the following number

```
c= 0x3FFFFFFF
```

and `a = an arbitrary integer number=Q`. My question is, why `a &= c` always is equal to "Q" and it does not change? for example, if I consider `a=10` then the result of `a &= c` is `10` if `a=256` the result of `a &= c` is `256`. Could you please explain why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Open your C++ book, and read the chapters that explain binary operations and bitwise operations. This is how bitwise operations work, and the full explanation will be in your C++ book, and is too long for a brief answer on stackoverflow.com, which is not really meant to be a replacement for a C++ book.

Comment: "My question is, why a &= c always is equal to "Q" and it does not change?" answer is it would change if you put proper value in `a`

Comment: `a = 0x40000000` and now it stops working, but there are lots of values for which it does work

Comment: @Slava supports Monica, No. for all numbers I put I got the same results. So I wonder if   0x3FFFFFFF, is something like unitary for this and bitwise operator.

Comment: @aminbk *"for all numbers I put I got the same results"* As harold already told you, the equation doesn't hold for `a = 0x40000000` (aka `1073741824` in decimal) and larger numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a and c are integer types and are composed of 32 bits in a computer. The first digit of an integer in a computer is the sign bit.The first digit of a positive number is 0, and the first digit of a negative number is 1. 0x3FFFFFFF is a special value. The first two digits of this number are 0, and the other digits are all 1. 1 & 1 = 1, 1 & 0 = 0. So when the number a a is positive and less than c, a & 0x3FFFFFFF is still a itself

Comment: You need to explain which first bit is 0. I think you mean the first one after the one which would make a signed int negative, but that really needs more explanation.

Comment: Sorry i got the number of digits wrong，，The first two digits of this number are 0, so when the number a is not greater than c and a is a positive number, a & c == a

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree. I did not mean that it is correct in total - though I admit my comment can be understood that way. You had my "agree" count on your "This is wrong." all the time. Now they spotted that detail, too. See "and less than c". I was kind of hoping for that, or would have continued nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

`a &= c` is the same as `a = a & c`, which calculates the binary and of `a` and `b` and then assign that value to `a` again - just in case you've mistaken what that operator does.

Now `a` contains almost only 1's. Then just think what each bit becomes: `1 & x` will always be `x`. Since you try with such low numbers only, none of them will change.

Try with `c=0xffffffff` and you will get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

You have not tested `a &= c;` with all possible values of `a` and are incorrect to assert it does not change the value of `a` in all cases.

`a &= c;` sets `a` to a value in which each bit is set if the two bits in the same position in `a` and in `c` are both set. If the two bits are not both set, 5he bit in the result is clear.

In `0x3FFFFFFF`, the 30 least significant bits are set. When this is used in `a &= c;` with any number in which higher bits are set, such as `0xC0000000`, the higher bits will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about bitwise `&` (`"and"`) operation and how it works, then there should be no question about this. Say, you have two numbers `a` and `b`. Each of them are n-bits long. Look,

```
a => a_(n-1) a_(n-2) a_(n-3) ... a_i ... a_2 a_1 a_0
b => b_(n-1) b_(n-2) b_(n-3) ... b_i ... b_2 b_1 b_0
```

Where a_0 and b_0 are the least significant bits and a_(n-1) and b_(n-1) are the most significant bits of a and b respectively.

Now, take a look at the `&` operation on two single binary bits.

```
1 & 1 = 1
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
0 & 0 = 0
```

So, the result of the & operation is 1 only when all bits are 1. If at least one bit is 0, then the result is 0.

Now, for n-bits long number,

```
a & b = (a_i & b_i); where `i` is from 0 to `n-1`
```

For example, if a and b both are 4 bits long numbers and `a = 5`, `b = 12`, then

```
a = 5 => a = 0101
b = 12 => b = 1100

if c = (a & b), c_i = (a_i & b_i) for i=0..3, here all numbers are 4 bits(0..3)
now, c = c_3 c_2 c_1 c_0
so c_3 = a_3 & b_3
   c_2 = a_2 & b_2
   c_1 = a_1 & b_1
   c_0 = a_0 & b_0

a    0 1 0 1
b    1 1 0 0
-------------
c    0 1 0 0 (that means c = 4)

therefore, c = a & b = 5 & 12 = 4
```

> Now, what would happen, if all of the bits in one number are `1`s?

Let's see.

```
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

so if any bit is fixed and it 1, then the result is the same as the other bit.

if `a = 5 (0101)` and `b = 15 (1111)`, then

```
a    0 1 0 1 (5)
b    1 1 1 1 (15)
------------------
c    0 1 0 1 (5, which is equal to a=5)
```

So, if any of the numbers has all bits are `1`s, then the `&` result is the same as the other number. Actually, for `a=any value of 4-bits long number`, you will get the result as `a`, since `b` is 4-bits long and all 4 bits are `1`s.

### **Now another issue would happen, when `a > 15` means a exceeds 4-bits**

For the above example, expand the bit size to 1 and change the value of a is 25.
`a = 25 (11001)` and `b = 15 (01111)`. Still, b is the same as before except the size. So the Most Significant Bit (MSB) is 0. Now,

```
a    1 1 0 0 1 (25)
b    0 1 1 1 1 (15)
----------------------
c    0 1 0 0 1 (9, not equal to a=25)
```

So, it is clear that we have to keep every single bit to 1 if we want to get the other number as the result of the `&` operation.

Now it is time to analyze the scenario you posted.
Here, `a &= c` is the same as `a = a & c`.

> We assumed that you are using 32-bit integer variables.

- You set `c = 0x3FFFFFFF` means `c = (2^30) - 1` or `c = 1073741823`

  ```
    a = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 (10)
  & c = 0011 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 (1073741823)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 (10, which is equal to a=10)

  and

    a = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 (256)
  & c = 0011 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 (1073741823)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 (256, which is equal to a=256)

  but, if a > c, say a=0x40000000 (1073741824, c+1 in base 10), then

    a = 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 (1073741824)
  & c = 0011 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 (1073741823)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (0, which is not equal to a=1073741823)
  ```

So, **your assumption ( the value of `a` after executing statement `a &= c` is the same as previous `a`) is true only if `a <= c`**

Comment: Thank you so much, I deeply appreciate it